# How do I display the text inside the WP editor for a page with a custom template?

Tags: page-template, editor

I am working in a Child theme on a page with a custom template. That custom template is not displaying any text that I enter into the wordpress editor. How do I "call" that text and display it in my custom template?

Is there something like

```
<?php get_editor_text(); ?>
```

I just need a way to display the text inside the editor box on the custom teplate page. How would I accomplish this in wordpress?

Comment: Do you mean `the_content();` or some other piece of text? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem. In order to access the content I used --

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

By adding that snippet of code directly into my template page I was able to easily add the content from the visual editor. I had attempted to use "the_content()" but this was nonfunctional because I was not within the loop.

The loop is an integral part of Wordpress and more information on the Loop can be found at http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop .

Answer (score 0):

You do it like in any other template. `the_title()` for the title, `the_content()` for the content etc.